# Bigram without repeated words

Tags: python, nltk, word-cloud, countvectorizer

I would like to analyze a text by counting bigrams. Unfortunately my text has plenty of repeated words (like: hello hello) that I don't want to be counted as bigrams.

My code is the following:

```
b = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words('this this is is a a test test'.split())
b.ngram_fd.keys()
```

that returns:

```
>> dict_keys([('this', 'this'), ('this', 'is'), ('is', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'test'), ('test', 'test')])
```

but I would like the output to be:

```
>> [('a', 'test'), ('is', 'a'), ('this', 'is')]
```

Do you have any suggestion, also using a different library?
Thank you in advance for any help.
Francesca

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
result_cleared = [x for x in b.ngram_fd.keys() if x[0] != x[1]]
```

---

**Edit**: If your texts are stored in a DataFrame, you can do the following:

```
# the dummy data from your comment
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['this is a stupid text with no no no sense','this song says na na na','this is very very very very annoying']})

def create_bigrams(text):
    b = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(text.split())
    return [x for x in b.ngram_fd.keys() if x[0] != x[1]]

df["bigrams"] = df["Text"].apply(create_bigrams)
df["bigrams"].apply(print)
```

This first adds a column containing the bigrams to the DataFrame and then prints the column values. If you want only the output without manipulating `df`, replace the last two lines with:

```
df["Text"].apply(create_bigrams).apply(print)
```

Comment: Thank you Georgy! Do you know also how to translate this in case texts are in a dataframe?

Comment: @botti23 You're welcome! This depends - do you mean if the texts are each inside a single DataFrame cell or if their words are in separate cells (in a single or in multiple columns)? Could you provide dummy data to work with?

Comment: Hi @georgy-kopshteyn, I meant if texts are inside a single dataframe cell, like in this case: 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['this is a stupid text with no no no sense','this song says na na na','this is very very very very annoying']})

Comment: @botti23 I have updated my post. Let me know whether this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove duplicated words before passing into the function `nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words`

```
words = 'this this is is a a test test'.split()
removed_duplicates = [first for first, second in zip(words, ['']+words) if first != second]

output:

['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

and then do:

```
b = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(removed_duplicates)
b.ngram_fd.keys()
```